# Stacked Barplot in R-Studio

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to build up a stacked barplot in R using barplot().

I have some Data given like :

```
counts1= table(questions$first)
counts1
0  1  #output
29 81 

counts2 = table(questions$snd)
counts2
 0  1 
40 48
```

And I would like to have that as an stacked barplot,  but what I get is :

```
barplot(c(counts1,counts2), main="BarPlot",
        col=c("darkblue","red"),horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

is it somehow possible to get 2 stacked bars here? I have tried a lot but I did not come up with a good solution. (I am quite new to R and dont want to use higher level plots like ggplots). And furthermore is it possible to get the relative frequency instead of absolut count values?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to `t`ranspose.

```
counts1 <- read.table(text="0  1  
29 81", header=TRUE) 
counts2 <- read.table(text="0  1  
40 48", header=TRUE) 

barplot(t(rbind(counts1=counts1, counts2=counts2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks well that worked t(rbind(...)... but why need the matrix to be transposed?

Comment: It's because the heights (i.e. observations) have to be in the rows for each variable (i.e. columns).